# How to remove / destroy a flowplayer instance?

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

After create a flowplayer instance like this:

```
$f("player", "flowplayer.swf", "my-video.flv");
```

When remove the container element directly, `$("#player").remove()`(using jQuery),

I found the `$f("player")` still there. How to remove the instance really?

Answer (score 2):

On BestKicker, we use `$f().unload()`.

Comment: if the container has no HTML content, $f.unload() does nothing

Answer (score 0):

I basically stored the contents of the DOM element that holds the player element in jQuery data on DOM ready:

```
$('.video-holder').each(function(i,el){
    $(el).data('init-state', $(el).html());
});
```

... then reset the contents (thereby detaching the Flowplayer instance) by calling the stored data back into the holder element's HTML to effectively 'reset' it:

```
$('.video-holder').each(function(i,el){
    $(el).html($(el).data('init-state'));
});
```

I've only tried this using Flowplayer manual setup, don't think it'd work on auto. Also it probably wouldn't be great performance-wise if you were doing it over and over as the original Flowplayer instance is still loaded in memory, just detached, but was the best solution I could come up with.