# remove FlowPlayer object from html

Tags: flowplayer

I use flash player -  flowplayer. and after using this player i need to remove it from my page. I use method `unload()`, but it does nothing. I tried to find question of this problem but find only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10311966). But there are no aswers. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shAV7/57/) we see that variable `fp` is steel exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the flowplayer documentation on [events](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/events/player.html) for `unload` it states:

> Unload: Unloads the player Flash component and replaces it with the original HTML content of the container element. This method does nothing if there was no HTML in the container.

Your example does not work because you have nothing within your container.  Typically this is an image (splash screen).  The user clicks on the image to start the video, the player is loaded.  Unloading the player at the end then removes the player and replaces the image.

I have created a working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shAV7/59/).

**Example**

```
<a href="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv" 
   class="player"
   style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;margin:10px auto"
   id="player">
    <!-- splash image inside the container -->
    <img src="/media/img/home/flow_eye.jpg"
         alt="Search engine friendly content" />
</a>

$f("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
    onFinish: function() {            
        this.unload();
    } 
});
```

Comment: And can You help, if I use 2 player on one screen. pressing to someone it unload another.

Comment: Target the player in JS using a class value instead of an id. e.g. Change `$f("player")` to `$f(".player")` and make sure the player html has the `player` CSS class.